# tbz2 archive built with gradle does not contain all expected files

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm new to AndroidStudio, so please bear with me.

Within my git controlled project I've added an additional task in gradle build file in the project root like so:

```
def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmm')
    return formattedDate
}

task myArchive(type:Tar) {
    from "${projectDir}"
    include ('app/src/**')
    include ('.git/**')
    baseName = 'Backup' + getDate()
    compression = Compression.BZIP2
}
```

My intention is to create a timestamped archive of the git repo and the current sources.
Problem is, that the .git directory is **not** included in the archive.
I tried to include different other directories as a test and replaced

```
include ('.git/**') 
with 
include ('.idea/**')
```

and this worked, so I'm out of ideas what goes wrong (no pun intended).
I found the debug output of the gradle rather unhelpful.

Oh, I'm using Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `**/.git/**`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it didn't work though.